# Are there any crafting professions that let you make upgrades?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I see that some items have empty upgrade slots. Are there any crafting professions that can make things to put into these slots? If so which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Guild Wars 2 [official wiki page on crafting](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting), every profession except for Chef can make some sort of [upgrade](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Upgrade_component) for weapons, armor and accessories.

- The [Artificer](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Artificer), [Huntsman](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Huntsman) and [Weaponsmith](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Weaponsmith) make sigils,
  which go on weapons.
- The [Armorsmith](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armorsmith), [Leatherworker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Leatherworker) and
  [Tailor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tailor) make runes, which go on armor.
- The [Jeweler](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Jeweler) makes
  Jewels, which along with their basic gemstone components can go in
  accessories as well as some weapons and armors (depending on the base
  gem).

Comment: Sigils can be put in upgrade slots? That's good to know, I thought they were just for making weapons.

Comment: Chef balances out the inability to make upgrades by being able to craft Dyes.

Comment: @Wipqozn Can Chefs (in reality) if they discovered every recipe make any dye in the game?

Comment: @Emerica: I believe Chefs can unlock ever dye.

Comment: @emerica The way that chef dyes work is they craft dyes like "unidentified gray spectrum dye (rare)" or "unidentified blue spectrum dye (uncommon). they cannot craft a specific dye. However, they can choose the color spectrum which is good for players looking for that elusive black/abyssal/celestial